# Traverse/fold a nested case class in Scala without boilerplate code

Tags: scala, fold, scala-cats

I have some case classes for a mix of sum and product types:

```
sealed trait Leaf
case class GoodLeaf(value: Int) extends Leaf
case object BadLeaf extends Leaf

case class Middle(left: Leaf, right: Leaf)

case class Container(leaf: Leaf)

case class Top(middle : Middle, container: Container, extraLeaves : List[Leaf])
```

I want to do some fold-like operations with this `Top` structure. Examples include:

- Count the occurrences of `BadLeaf`
- Sum all the values in the `GoodLeaf`s

Here is some code that does the operations:

```
object Top {
  def fold[T](accu: T)(f : (T, Leaf) => T)(top: Top) = {
    val allLeaves =  top.container.leaf :: top.middle.left :: top.middle.right :: top.extraLeaves
    allLeaves.foldLeft(accu)(f)
  }

  private def countBadLeaf(count: Int, leaf : Leaf) = leaf match {
    case BadLeaf => count + 1
    case _ => count
  }

  def countBad(top: Top): Int = fold(0)(countBadLeaf)(top)

  private def sumGoodLeaf(count: Int, leaf : Leaf) = leaf match {
    case GoodLeaf(v) => count + v
    case _ => count
  }

  def sumGoodValues(top: Top) = fold(0)(sumGoodLeaf)(top)
}
```

The real life structure I am dealing with is significantly more complicated than the example I made up. Are there any techniques that could help me avoid writing lots of boilerplate code?

I already have the `cats` library as a dependency, so a solution that uses that lib would be preferred.  I am open to including new dependencies in order to solve this problem.

For my particular example, the definition is not recursive, but I'd be interested in seeing a solution that works for recursive definitions also.

Comment: *I know how to write code to do this, but it will be tedious.* Show the boilerplate in question first; then we'll talk.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a function returning all leaves for `Top`, like you did with `allLeaves`, so you can just work with a `List[Leaf]` (with all the existing `fold` and other functions the Scala library, Cats, etc provide).

For example :

```
def topLeaves(top: Top): List[Leaf] =
  top.container.leaf :: top.middle.left :: top.middle.right :: top.extraLeaves

val isBadLeaf: Leaf => Boolean = {
  case BadLeaf => true
  case _       => false
}

val leafValue: Leaf => Int = {
  case GoodLeaf(v) => v
  case _           => 0
}
```

Which you could use as

```
import cats.implicits._
// or
// import cats.instances.int._
// import cats.instances.list._
// import cats.syntax.foldable._

val leaves = topLeaves(someTop)

val badCount   = leaves.count(isBadLeaf)
val badAndGood = leaves.partition(isBadLeaf) // (List[Leaf], List[Leaf])
val sumLeaves  = leaves.foldMap(leafValue)
```

I am not sure if this helps with your actual use case ? In general with a heterogeneous structure (like your `Top`) you probably want to convert it somehow to something more homogeneous (like a `List[Leaf]` or `Tree[Leaf]`) where you can fold over.

If you have a recursive structure you could look at some talks about recursion schemes (with the [Matryoshka](https://github.com/slamdata/matryoshka) library in Scala).